# ROI on Forex Trading

Tags: investing, trading, foreign-exchange, rate-of-return

I have lately been reading up on what Forex Trading is and how it works. In many sources, it is described that a consistent investor can generate `15%` return annually.

My question is, what is this return based on? Is it based on your margin or is it based on your total position (which includes leverage).

Lets say you have a margin of `$1000` and your broker provides you with a leverage of `100:1`, so you have a position of `$100,000`.

Now is your return `15%` of `$1000 = $150` or is it `15%` of `$100,000 = $15,000`?

Comment: it is based on your actual initial capital.

Answer (score 5):

Please, please don't believe all the financial sales pitches you will hear in your life.  Consistent?? give me a break.  The returns promised include the effects of leverage.  That same leverage can also generate 100% losses.

Answer (score 3):

To make a return of 15% on $100k the currency you are trading would have to move by 15%. This does not happen to often. In FX trading you are mostly trying to capture and profit from small moves in a currency pair.

Based on this, in my opinion, the 15% return would be based on your own capital, ie. the $1000. This would be how I would work out my return when dealing with margin.

Comment: Since virtually all retail forex traders do so with very high levels of leverage, you wouldn't need a cumulative 15% of moves in order to net a 15% return (or loss!).